# when Im trying to call the function and return a value its showing Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

While running this code

```
def recommend(features, feature_list):
    neighbors = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=6, algorithm="brute", metric="euclidean")
    neighbors.fit(feature_list)

    indices = neighbors.kneighbors([features])         # <=

    return indices

if uploaded_file is not None:
    if save_uploaded_file(uploaded_file):
        # display the file
        display_image = Image.open(uploaded_file)
        st.image(display_image)
        # feature extract
        features = feature_extraction(
            os.path.join("uploads", uploaded_file.name), model
        )
        # st.text(features)
        # recommendention
        indices = recommend(features, feature_list)      # <=
```

Im getting this error

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=    ['images\\10000.jpg' 'images\\10001.jpg' 'images\\10002.jpg' ... 'images\\9997.jpg' 'images\\9998.jpg' 'images\\9999.jpg']. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`
```

Comment: From the error, it seems the neighbors function is expecting a 2D array, and instead, you're giving it a list. Try doing `neighbors.kneighbors(features)` instead of with the `[]`

Answer (score 0):

The line 4 in your code ,

> indices = neighbors.kneighbors([features])

should be having 2 arguments (a 2D array).

You have however given a 1D array.

the `kneighbours()` function takes in minimum 2 arguments as per the documentation of [KNN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html) :

For finding the K-neighbors of a point, the correct syntax is :

> kneighbors([X, n_neighbors, return_distance])

return_distance is by default False.

Ref:

[image]

Hence you need to give n_neighbours along with the features array.

Your code should hence be changed to :

```
#6 neighbours specified earlier

indices = neighbors.kneighbors([features],n_neighbours=6)
```